# Add city name field to shipping zone - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using [Departamentos y Ciudades de Colombia para Woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/departamentos-y-ciudades-de-colombia-para-woocommerce/) plugin which transforms input field for city/town to select field in the checkout section with the prepopulated list of cities/town provided in the plugin file.

I want to add the same city select field to the form to create shipping zones in Woocommerce. Although Woocommerce supports adding Continents/Countries/States/Postcodes but does not support adding city names in the shipping zone. I can use postcodes but that doesn't work as some countries do not support the postcode system or they cover larger areas on a single postcode.

Can someone guide me on which classes or files of the Woocommerce core need to be extended so that it supports city names for shipping zones? I want to create shipping zones based on city names. I think methods of [`WC_Shipping_Zone`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Zone.html) needs to be overridden. Help me that which `actions` and `filters` of Woocommerce are of interest for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am the creator of plugin, see code reference in github 
https://github.com/saulmoralespa/departamentos-y-ciudades-de-colombia-para-woocommerce/blob/master/includes/filter-by-cities.php

I added filter by cities how method shipping optional

Comment: Hello thank you, I can see the section but I can't see how to set up the rules, as there's any options available?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found the trick, the filter by cities is confusing though I hadn't noticed it is a shipping method you have to select while creating the shipping zone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
add_filter( 'wc_city_select_cities', 'my_cities' );
/**
 * Replace XX with the country code. Instead of YYY, ZZZ use actual  state codes.
 */

function my_cities( $cities ) {
    $cities['XX'] = array(
        'YYY' => array(
            'City1',
            'City2'
        ),
        'YYY' => array(
            'City Center',
            'City Corniche'
        )
    );
    return $cities;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please explain how and why this code works. https:stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue, however I found that I could have inserted a php file to remedy this.

1. Go to: yourwebsite/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/states
2. You will see php files for countries with States inserted
3. If you open one you will see the code format

Below is the php code for Argentina

```css
<?php
/**
 * Argentinian provinces
 *
 * @package WooCommerce/i18n
 * @version 2.4.0
 */

global $states;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$states['AR'] = array(
 'C' => __( 'Ciudad Aut&oacute;noma de Buenos Aires', 'woocommerce' ),
 'B' => __( 'Buenos Aires', 'woocommerce' ),
 'K' => __( 'Catamarca', 'woocommerce' ),
 'H' => __( 'Chaco', 'woocommerce' ),
 'U' => __( 'Chubut', 'woocommerce' ),
 'X' => __( 'C&oacute;rdoba', 'woocommerce' ),
 'W' => __( 'Corrientes', 'woocommerce' ),
 'E' => __( 'Entre R&iacute;os', 'woocommerce' ),
 'P' => __( 'Formosa', 'woocommerce' ),
 'Y' => __( 'Jujuy', 'woocommerce' ),
 'L' => __( 'La Pampa', 'woocommerce' ),
 'F' => __( 'La Rioja', 'woocommerce' ),
 'M' => __( 'Mendoza', 'woocommerce' ),
 'N' => __( 'Misiones', 'woocommerce' ),
 'Q' => __( 'Neuqu&eacute;n', 'woocommerce' ),
 'R' => __( 'R&iacute;o Negro', 'woocommerce' ),
 'A' => __( 'Salta', 'woocommerce' ),
 'J' => __( 'San Juan', 'woocommerce' ),
 'D' => __( 'San Luis', 'woocommerce' ),
 'Z' => __( 'Santa Cruz', 'woocommerce' ),
 'S' => __( 'Santa Fe', 'woocommerce' ),
 'G' => __( 'Santiago del Estero', 'woocommerce' ),
 'V' => __( 'Tierra del Fuego', 'woocommerce' ),
 'T' => __( 'Tucum&aacute;n', 'woocommerce' ),
);
```

I copied that code format to a new file and replaced the States with the information from my country and I was able to create shipping zones for each of the states in my country.

This is my php code

```css
<?php
/**
 * Belizean Districts
 *
 * @package WooCommerce/i18n
 * @version 2.4.0
 */

global $states;

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

$states['BZ'] = array(
 'C' => __( 'Corozal', 'woocommerce' ),
 'B' => __( 'Orange Walk', 'woocommerce' ),
 'K' => __( 'Belize', 'woocommerce' ),
 'H' => __( 'Cayo', 'woocommerce' ),
 'U' => __( 'Stann Creek', 'woocommerce' ),
 'X' => __( 'Toledo', 'woocommerce' ),
 'W' => __( 'Caye Caulker', 'woocommerce' ),
 'E' => __( 'San Pedro', 'woocommerce' ),
 
);
```

Comment: Well, I am interested in creating shipping zone by city not state. States are by default supported by WooCommerce.